# .htaccess rewrite rule?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite my `/index.php` to `/index`, and my `/register.php` to `/register`, but it doesn't work!

This is my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^register/index$ register.php
RewriteRule ^index$ index.php
```

But... It isn't rewriting... Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule    ^register/?$    register.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^index/?$    index.php    [NC,L]
```

Adding Above code will make your the /register show /register .

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing the preceding forward slashes:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/register/index$ register.php
RewriteRule ^/index$ index.php
```

Check out the docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html#ToC2 - all of the examples have preceding forward slashes.